I want to use Redis cache with my Spring Boot project (consider 3.3.1 version). What exactly and bare minimum configurations required?
I understand that Spring Boot offers extensive auto-configuration capabilities for connecting to services like Redis. From what I know, specifying a few properties in application.properties should be sufficient to connect my Spring Boot application to a local Redis server.
However, in reviewing the Spring documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/reference/redis/redis-cache.html), I noticed recommendations to manually configure RedisCacheManager beans and connection factories. Given Spring Boot's reputation for auto-configuration, why would additional bean configurations be necessary? Wouldn't properties such as the following be adequate?
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.cache-null-values=true
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379

This question applies broadly, not only to Redis but also to other applications like Apache Kafka and Elasticsearch. Shouldn't defining properties in application.properties be sufficient to establish connections to these applications running locally?
I appreciate your insights. Thank you.
